# Angular Unit Test, how to test component function with service call

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to test the following piece of code:

```
getEmployeeDetails() {
    const employeeURL = 'apiURL';
    this.employeeService.getEmployees(employeeURL).subscribe((result) => {
      result.forEach((item, index) => {
        const addressURL = '/address/' + item.employeeId;
        this.employeeService.getAddress(addressURL).subscribe((result2) => {
            result2.forEach((item2, index2) => {
            
            });
        });
      });
    });
}
```

but got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: result.forEach is not a function thrown

When trying to test using the below Unit test case

```
 describe('employee test', () => {
  const employees = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Raju'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Arun'}
  ];  
        const mockEmployeeService = jasmine.createSpyObj('EmployeeService', ['getEmployees']);
      
        const getDataSpy = mockEmployeeService.getEmployees.and.returnValue( of(employees) );  
      
      
      beforeEach(async(() => {        
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [...],
              imports: [...],
              schemas: [...],
              providers: [
                { provide: EmployeeService, useValue: mockEmployeeService }
              ],
          });
     });        
    
    it('should call api and return value', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
    
        component.getEmployeeDetails();
      });
    );
```

Please give suggestions on how to test the above piece of code.

Comment: Are you mocking the response of getEmployees method? Share test case code.

Comment: @RiteshWaghela - I have updated the question with the mock code. After seeing your comments, searched online and came up with the above test case code. Please give suggestion on how to test the getEmployeeDetails() method,  with the service response data.

Comment: const getDataSpy = mockEmployeeService.getEmployees.and.returnValue( of(employees) );   - Here employees needs to be an array and not an object. please check the same.

Comment: `getEmployees` in your test won't return anything and your code expects it to return an array. You can't call `forEach` on `undefined` hence the error. Simply debugging your test should of made this obvious.

Comment: @Liam - He is returning an observable of employee array from his test. Should this not work?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela, Liam - Based on your comments, I have tried and updated the question, now the test case is passed. Thanks for your support, you people are awesome.